# After migrating users the user Ids are different

Tags: user-management

I'm trying to migrate users to another instance. Both the source & destination are the same - v8.2.

There is an option `Serialize users and roles` in the Domain Manager dialog. Using that I have serialized the users & roles of a custom domain, then copied the folder to the corresponding location in the destination and then did `Revert users and roles`.

All the users & roles migrated successfully. But when I compare the `UserId`s of these users (*aspnet_Users* table), the source & destination Ids are different.

Aren't they supposed to be the same.

The reason for my concern is, I have to later migrate a large no. of users.
The next step which is updating passwords using the Sitecore's [`TransferUserPasswords.aspx`](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/242631) is not an option because the source system cant access the target system and also the no. of users is huge.

So, I wanted to update the passwords using SQL update statements.
When I checked the code in the aspx page, it uses the SQL update statement in the backend and by matching UserIds.

In my case they turned out to be different. Is this a bug or did I miss anything.

Comment: The primary key for a user is userName; e.g. `sitecore\admin`. The provider specific ID should not assumed to be constant.

Comment: @MarkCassidy. I'm just wondering how the `TransferUserPassword.aspx` page works, because it is using UserId to update the passwords.

Comment: You can't just SQL move passwords across from one instance to another. Machine keys, encryption, stuff.

Comment: @MarkCassidy I get your point. But Sitecore's solution was doing the same. So, I was just thinking abt hw it can when in my case the UserIds came out different